# Setting menu weight for "Edit" and "View" items in a node

Tags: 7, routes

I am trying to rearrange the order of my menu items for my custom node. Most of the menu items are created programmatically in hook_menu() so I can simply set the weights for those which works great. But I would like to move the edit menu item down the list a bit but I can't find a way to change its weight from the default of zero.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this with [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

Another option would be to leave the edit at 0 and change the weights of the items you can adjust to work around the edit.